# Drupal 7 file upload (without hook_form)

Tags: php, javascript, post, file-upload, drupal-7

Here is a conundrum that's had me stumped for the past few days. I am using a modal form in Drupal 7, so working outside of the hook_form system, trying to upload an image. The form is submitted through an ajax post, which prevents me from submitting the file along with the post. what I've done is in the ajax callback, create a new form element with the file input and then trigger a submit, posting to my module-defined page.

Original input element:

```
<input type="file" id="chooseImage" name"someImage" class="form-file">
```

js triggering submit:

```
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url:$('#originalForm').attr('action'),
data: data,
success: function(response) {
    if (response.success) {
        $('<form id="imageForm" method="POST" action="upload/image/'+response.data.nid+'"></form>').appendTo($('#imageSubmit'));
        $('#chooseImage').appendTo($('#imageForm')); 
        console.log($('#imageForm'));
        $('#imageForm').submit(function(e){
            console.log(e);
            alert('freeze! hammertime...');
        });
        //This should post the file but it isn't...
        $('#imageForm').trigger('submit');
    }
},
dataType:'json'
});
```

The submit event shows the file properties just fine. However, on the backend, where my page callbacks end...

```
    function myModule_image_upload($param){
        error_log('number of files = '.sizeof($_FILES));
    }
```

I am showing no files posted. I am guessing that the browser is removing the file data in the post after .submit() runs and if that is the case, I'm probably powerless to do anything about it, so I'll have to implement a separate menu within the hook system for image uploads.

Also, whatever it is that this is really doing, it seems to permanently break watchdog, forcing me to re-import a fresh dump.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('<form id="imageForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="upload/image/'+response.data.nid+'"></form>').appendTo($('#imageSubmit'));
```

So you forgot to set the enctype.

Another error:

```
<input type="file" id="chooseImage" name"someImage" class="form-file">
```

Should be

```
<input type="file" id="chooseImage" name="someImage" class="form-file"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, that is an important piece and would likely cause me trouble at some point, but unfortunately, it did not solve this particular problem.

Comment: And that would do it (missing =).